# Capistrano 3 not updating the releases

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, capistrano

I am using Capistrano 3 to deploy my app to the production server. 
My server has system wide install of rvm. There is nothing extra ordinary about the deploy script.
However when i run `cap production deploy` The deploy script gives out successful messages and seems that deploy went without a problem. 
However when I check the latest release folder is not updated and only the repo folder is updated.
This was supposed to be much easier while using Capistrano 2. But the respective commands to create symlinks etc all are shown to be passed in the console log while depoying while in the server nothing is being done.
Am I missing something about the capistrano 3 changes.
Ask if you need more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capistrano 3 changed the symlink task, if you overrode it or called it specifically like deploy:create_symlink, you may want to audit your code.